# How I can calculate the max for these data

Tags: r

Here is a part of my data

```
dat<-read.table (text="
Flower  A1  A2  A3  TM  MN  B1  B2  B3
F1  12  9   11  12  0.56    19  1   12
F2  11  16  13  13  0.65    22  4   12
F3  10  12  14  11  0.44    29  9   12
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to calculate Max for column MN. For example, for value 0.44, the max is max(0.44,1-0.44)= 0.56.
I struggle to get it with a data frame.

Here is the outcome of the interest:

```
Flower  A   TM  B   MN  Max
F1  12  12  19  0.56    0.56
F2  11  13  22  0.65    0.65
F3  10  11  29  0.44    0.56
F1  9   12  1   0.56    0.56
F2  16  13  4   0.65    0.65
F3  12  11  9   0.44    0.56
F1  11  12  12  0.56    0.56
F2  13  13  12  0.65    0.65
F3  14  11  12  0.44    0.56
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `reshape` and `ave`.

```
reshape(dat, varying=list(2:4, 7:9), direction='long', idvar='Flower') |>
  transform(Max=ave(MN, Flower, FUN=max))
#      Flower TM   MN time A1 B1  Max
# F1.1     F1 12 0.56    1 12 19 0.56
# F2.1     F2 13 0.65    1 11 22 0.65
# F3.1     F3 11 0.44    1 10 29 0.44
# F1.2     F1 12 0.56    2  9  1 0.56
# F2.2     F2 13 0.65    2 16  4 0.65
# F3.2     F3 11 0.44    2 12  9 0.44
# F1.3     F1 12 0.56    3 11 12 0.56
# F2.3     F2 13 0.65    3 13 12 0.65
# F3.3     F3 11 0.44    3 14 12 0.44
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

Comment: Thank you, It seems that it does work on these particular hypothetical data. However, it does not work on my data. For example, if you use  transfer  for Max, you will not get a proper result.

Comment: @user330 Well, in this case, you should either adapt the code to your data, or make an example that resembles your data better. From both you will learn a lot :)

Comment: @user330 You probably mean `transform`. That's easy, it basically takes a data frame and creates variables in it, try `transform(mtcars, foo=9999)`. In the code the data is piped with `|>` into `transform` and you can use it to directly create variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
transform(
    reshape(
        setNames(dat, gsub("(\\d+)", ".\\1", names(dat))),
        direction = "long",
        idvar = c("Flower", "TM", "MN"),
        varying = -c(1, 5, 6)
    ),
    Max = pmax(MN, 1 - MN)
)
```

which gives

```
             Flower TM   MN time  A  B  Max
F1.12.0.56.1     F1 12 0.56    1 12 19 0.56
F2.13.0.65.1     F2 13 0.65    1 11 22 0.65
F3.11.0.44.1     F3 11 0.44    1 10 29 0.56
F1.12.0.56.2     F1 12 0.56    2  9  1 0.56
F2.13.0.65.2     F2 13 0.65    2 16  4 0.65
F3.11.0.44.2     F3 11 0.44    2 12  9 0.56
F1.12.0.56.3     F1 12 0.56    3 11 12 0.56
F2.13.0.65.3     F2 13 0.65    3 13 12 0.65
F3.11.0.44.3     F3 11 0.44    3 14 12 0.56
```